# Theory: Mysql - primary key used twice in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am creating document management system that has one master table. All records are indexed in this single table with a doc_id primary key.A single record may have a relationship with multiple records in the same table. I would like show this relationship within a link table. Is it possible to reference within the link table to use primary key  to create a unique compound key?

Eg doc_id = 1 is related to doc_id = 2 and doc_ = 3. So in the link table I have:

```
docidlink (doc_id, doc_id)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
```

Is this possible? Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why that would not be possible.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, that table should work fine except that you would want to make the columns have different names IE (doc_id, linked_doc_id). if you want to ensure uniqueness then add a unique key on both columns.